# Where I can find ATTRIBUTES in freebsd's library man page?

Tags: linux, freebsd, libc

In Linux, there is a part in library man page called ATTRIBUTES which has some useful information like wheter a function is thread-safe. So I tried looking into the FreeBSD man page but I found nothing. And I found that FreeBSD function library's man page is quite old, is it proper to try FreeBSD as a programming OS?

Comment: What library are you talking about? `libc`?

Comment: @arrowd Yes, libc